# HBase: how put/get knows which region server to write to?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, hdfs, bigdata

In HBase, how the put/get operations know which region server the row should be written to?
In case of multiple rows to be read how multiple region servers are contacted and the results are retrieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume your question is simply curiosity, since this behavior is abstracted from the user and you shouldn't care.

---

> In HBase, how the put/get operations know which region server the row should be written to?

From the [hbase documentation book](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client):

> The HBase client HTable is responsible for finding RegionServers that are serving the particular row range of interest. It does this by querying the .META. and -ROOT- catalog tables (TODO: Explain). After locating the required region(s), the client directly contacts the RegionServer serving that region (i.e., it does not go through the master) and issues the read or write request. This information is cached in the client so that subsequent requests need not go through the lookup process. Should a region be reassigned either by the master load balancer or because a RegionServer has died, the client will requery the catalog tables to determine the new location of the user region.

So first step is looking up in meta and root to determine where it is, then it contacts that regionserver to do that work.

---

> In case of multiple rows to be read how multiple region servers are contacted and the results are retrieved?

There are two ways to read from HBase in general: [scanners](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html) and [gets](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#get%28org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get%29).

If you run multiple gets, those will each individually fetch those records separately. Each one of those is possibly going to a different region server.

The scanner will simply look for the start of the range and then move forward from there. Sometimes it needs to move to a different regionserver when it reaches the end, but the client handles that behind the scenes. If there is some way to design the table such that your multiple gets is a scan and not a series of gets, you should hypothetically have better performance.

Comment: Thanks Donald. It helps me to understand. As I understand from your answer it is completely client's responsibility(under the hood using meta information) to locate the Region Server(s).

Answer (score 1):

Providing the same scenario and explanation from BigTable Paper: "The client library caches tablet locations. If the client
does not know the location of a tablet, or if it discovers
that cached location information is incorrect, then
it recursively moves up the tablet location hierarchy.
If the client's cache is empty, the location algorithm
requires three network round-trips, including one read
from Chubby. If the client's cache is stale, the location
algorithm could take up to six round-trips, because stale
cache entries are only discovered upon misses (assuming
that METADATA tablets do not move very frequently).
Although tablet locations are stored in memory, so no
GFS accesses are required, we further reduce this cost
in the common case by having the client library prefetch
tablet locations: it reads the metadata for more than one
tablet whenever it reads the METADATA table."

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf